# How to increment a cell reference by one inside a hyperlink equation to apply to a whole column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, office365, hyperlink, microsoft-excel-365

So I have a column in (Sheet1) that I want to lead to the same cell number in another sheet (Sheet2) when I click each cell.

When I tried to use the hyperlink function, I typed the first equation as follows.

`=HYPERLINK("#Sheet2!B2",Sheet2!B2)`

I want to automatically use it for all cells, so that I need B2 to turn into B3,B4,B5, etc.

When I try to use the drag method to select every other cell under B2, the problem is that the first part of the equation is inside quotation marks so excel doesn't treat it as a number and therefore doesn't increase it while the second part works well with the drag method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following, edited to fit your exact circumstances:

```
=HYPERLINK("#Sheet2!B"&ROW(),Sheet2!B2)
```

You must have the <kbd>#</kbd>. As to the rest, if you do like in the second answer, what is being added to the hardcoded string portion is NOT the address `B2` but rather the value IN `B2`, which surely would rarely give a result that even makes a working link and probably never give a correct result.

However, using `ROW()`, adjusted with "plus or minus some value" if the link is not, itself, in row 2. So if it's in row 38, you'd edit it to be `ROW()-36`.

The first answer is not right either. If you have a single, say, cell reference in some cell, let's say `=A3` is in cell ZA34, then double-clicking on cell ZA34 should jump you to cell A3. That is NOT the case if you allow editing IN cells rather than just in the formula bar as double clicking is hijacked to open the editing of the cell. But if you're sane, you have not chosen to allow in-cell editing so no worries...

So what the first answerer is seeing is not the hyperlink working, but rather the referenced-cell-seeking action. You can see that by noticing that the action takes double clicking to occur, not a single click, and also that the Intellisense aid does not pop up (if you have a working hyperlink, it pops up and tells you where it will take you if you click on it).

Bonus point, since it might be desired for your hyperlinks and no one ever mentions it. If you create a simple hyperlink, nothing special, and have something appear in the cell, in your case the value currently at the target, you'll note the thing that appears is underlined and that you must click the underlined region of the cell for the jump to occur. Click on whitespace and nothing happens except that the cell is now selected and you might edit it.

If you'd like the jump to occur no matter where someone clicks inside the cell, then go to formatting for the cell, select the `Alignment` tab, `Horizontal Alignment`, and pick the `Fill` option. Doing so can cut way down on people reporting your hyperlinks don't work. I don't use it on my own spreadsheets, but in ones written for others to use, I always do.

Comment: That's exactly what i was looking for, thanks genius worked like a charm, i've lost hope and you came and saved me,

Answer (score 0):

Build the link dynamically by concatenating the sheetname and the cell (B2 in this case). Your formula will be:

```
=HYPERLINK("Sheet2!" & B2,Sheet2!B2)
```

Then drag it down to fill the other cells.

Comment: it shows reference isn't valid

Comment: Remove the `#`.

Answer (score 0):

`=HYPERLINK(Sheet2!B2;Sheet2!B2)`

This works in my excel, without hash & quotation marks.  Just copy&paste or drag it below.

(cannot comment therefore posted this answer.)

Comment: it's not working it shows error in Formula